# Centering together 4 cells of a display-table: working on Firefox, not working on Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to put these 4 cells together and it's not working on Chrome (it used to work before, haven't changed it), but it's working on Firefox. There is space between the cells in a row when I'm using Chrome. This shouldn't happen. This is the page I'm talking about: http://pablotv.me/chetochine/novosite/pt/marketing-research/

(Unfortunately, I can't post images because of my reputation on StackOverflow, I've just signed up and I'm an amateur yet)

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="mktwrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div id="box-1" class="box">
        <img id="image-1" src="1.png"/>
        <span class="caption full-caption">
        <p>Content1</p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box">
        <img id="image-2" src="2.png"/>
        <span class="caption full-caption">
        <p>Content2</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div id="box-3" class="box">
        <img id="image-3" src="3.png"/>
        <span class="caption full-caption">
        <p>Content3</p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="box-4" class="box">
        <img id="image-4" src="4.png"/>
        <span class="caption full-caption">
        <p>Content4</p>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
#mktwrapper {
    font: 24pt normal Arial, sans-serif;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#mktwrapper .row {
    display: table-row;
}

#mktwrapper .box {
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 350px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #mktwrapper .box {
        display: block;
    }
}

#mktwrapper .box img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

#mktwrapper .box .caption {
    background-color: rgba(252,252,252,0.92);
    position: absolute;
    color: #111;
    z-index: 100;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    left: 0;
}

#mktwrapper .box .full-caption {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    top: -350px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px;
}

#mktwrapper .box:hover .full-caption {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -o-transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Still cant understand where is the issue upload your image [here](http://imgur.com/) and post image URL here.

Comment: Thanks @divy3993! Here is how it looks on Chrome: [link](http://i.imgur.com/FTc0TiC.png)

And on Firefox [link](http://i.imgur.com/rRQXw46.png)

Comment: So you want  it to look like in firefox, but not like chrome.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: check the Answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it might work:

**CSS** : Update these code lines to your CSS.

```
.row {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.box
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

> **NOTE :** If you have multiple div's with class 'row' than use inline CSS or else would effect all div containing class 'row'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @divy3993! It works! It's not perfect - there's a space between rows and columns, but this will work for now (see: [link](http://i.imgur.com/IRuFQjS.png)

:)